# How to view the list hidden in breadcrumb?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I am using Bootstrap - Breadcrumb in my HTML page. If the text overflows or the width of the list is higher, I used ellipsis (overflow: hidden). How to view the list hidden under the ellipsis on clicking ellipsis or Home?
Please run the code in expand snippet, to see the different levels...

```css
/* Breadcrumbs from http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/triangle-breadcrumbs-arrows */

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(173, 173, 173);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 24px;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
  padding: 6px 18px 6px 24px;
}


/** Default button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #ebebeb;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #adadad;
}


/* The responsive part */

.btn-breadcrumb>*>div {
  /* With less: .text-overflow(); */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.btn-breadcrumb>*:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}


/* === For phones =================================== */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn-breadcrumb>*:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    display: block;
  }
  .btn-breadcrumb>* div {
    max-width: 60px;
  }
}


/* === For tablets ================================== */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  .btn-breadcrumb>*:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    display: block;
  }
  .btn-breadcrumb>* div {
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}


/* === For desktops ================================== */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .btn-breadcrumb>*:nth-last-child(-n+6) {
    display: block;
  }
  .btn-breadcrumb>* div {
    max-width: 170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Breadcrumbs 2 (8 elements)</h2>
    <div id="bc2" class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
      <div class="btn btn-default">...</div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 1. A very very long one to truncate</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 2</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 3</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 4</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 5. A very very long one to truncate</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 6</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 7</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 8</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 9</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 10</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 11</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 12</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 13</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
        <div>label 14</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

> Blockquote